# Python / mysql cronjob won't execute properly

Tags: python, mysql, json, cron

I'm working on a Python script that loads items from a generated JSON file and eventually inserts these into a MySQL database provided that they do not already exist. The execution is scheduled for each quarter of an hour through a cronjob. However, it looks like whenever this script is ran from this cronjob, nothing gets inserted because the items would already exist. But when I run the script myself (even directly after cron ran it), it does insert new rows..

The cron entry looks like this:

```
*/15   *       *       *       *       /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/scraper/scraper.py > /home/ubuntu/scraper/log
```

The application consists of two scripts: a scraper that puts newly found items out to a JSON file, and one that checks if the items already exist in the database and inserts them if not. That last script is imported and called from the first one as a function. Both files start with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

... although I don't suspect this to be an environment issue. For the database handling I use the `mysql.connector` module. I'm sure that the database script is able to read the JSON file, as I do see the items being printed.

When running from cron, it seems the script doesn't get past this query:

```
SELECT i.id FROM items i LEFT JOIN properties p ON p.id = i.id WHERE MD5(CONCAT(i.address_norm, p.source)) = MD5(CONCAT(%s, %s))
```

When the row count returns 1, it continues to the next item. Again, when I run it manually, it works just fine. Moreover, I don't see any errors thrown in the logs I save for the cronjobs. I have no idea where to look at this point.

Any idea what might go wrong?

Comment: Try adding `2>&1` to the end of your cron job line to also capture stderr in your log file, your current command only redirects stdout, so you might miss something